# ifelse works with mutate in R, why not in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, dplyr

I have this line of code working in "normal" R:

```
damage <- damage %>% mutate( EVTYPE = ifelse(grepl("winter", EVTYPE,
    ignore.case=T), "Winter Weather", EVTYPE))
```

However, the exact same line of code in knitr results in strange behavior.  Instead of the value of EVTYPE being left alone if the grep fails, it is instead changed into a number.  Perhaps an index.

The output in R of head(unique(damage$EVTYPE)) is:

> [1] "TORNADO"                   "TSTM WIND"                 "HAIL"                      "ICE STORM/FLASH FLOOD"
>   [5] "Winter Weather"            "HURRICANE OPAL/HIGH WINDS"

whereas in knitr it is:

> [1] "407"            "423"            "134"            "239"
>    [5] "Winter Weather" "223"

Is this a bug?  Is there some reason this isn't expected to work in knitr?

Comment: It looks like in your R environment it's a character vector while in your knitr environment it's a factor. Have you forgotten to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` on read.table or `data.frame`?

Comment: That was it!  Thank you very much.  Put that down as an answer and I'll choose it.

Comment: if this is the whole line of code in the original context (I appreciate that it might be modified from its original context), why bother using `%>%`?  `damage <- mutate(damage, ...)` works identically to `damage <- damage %>% mutate(...)` and is shorter ...

Comment: @BenBolker or even shorter (if using magrittr) `damage %<>% mutate(EVTYPE = ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in your R environment it's a character vector while in your knitr environment it's a factor. Have you forgotten to use stringsAsFactors = FALSE on read.table or data.frame?